# MySQL: Optimizing indexes after importing tables

Tags: mysql, indexing, explain

I have imported a database from MySQL 5.6 into MySQL 5.5 (existing database). Now the problem is some stored procedures are taking too much time to execute. So I have checked execution plan by using "Explain" command. I have found some indexes are not working on MySQL 5.5 version but same indexes are working fine on MySQL 5.6 version. Below screenshots are for reference.

MySQL 5.5:
[Explain Result MySQL 5.5 Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AppoX.png)

MySQL 5.6:
[Explain Result MySQL 5.6 Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msT5c.png)

Please let me know if I am missing anything or if I need to change anything on MySQL 5.5.

Comment: please share the schema so that we can understand the problem better.

Comment: If you want help, you need to provide the `SELECT` and the `SHOW CREATE TABLEs`.